# How do you keep a Perforce repo downstream of git updated?

Tags: git, github, git-p4

At my company, we're starting a pilot program to use GitHub:Enterprise and determine if it is a suitable replacement for Perforce. Until such a time as the company is comfortable with it, we're going to be using both systems, though individual teams will be either using only one or the other.

One thing we *would* like to do though is push changes seen in project mainlines into the Perforce repo, just so there's an escape hatch if the pilot goes belly up. This will keep management happier if we run into snags.

I've used git-p4 for a while now, and am familiar with the way it works, so I know that I can't just naively use it to automatically push changes in (for those not aware: Every time you push to the perforce repository, all the pushed commits are rewritten).

Does anyone have any experience keeping a Perforce downstream of git up to date? Is there an automated way to do this? Perhaps with some combination of scripts and GitHub API hooks?

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, I'd suggest keeping the P4 and master branches in git separate, and cherry-picking new revisions off master into P4 as they arrive.  You'd probably want to keep the integration in a separate git repo that's not used for anything else.